# do AJAX call on page load through hash tag in URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using isotope, here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/DA3wF/

Or, alternatively, a demo I have set up: http://nerdi.net/isotope-test.html

There's an option `filter: selector`

How could I pass a filter, ex: `index.html#green` that on page load, would filter to the `.green` class? is this possible?

Comment: You forgot the link to your jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry I'm retarded, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/DA3wF/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
filter: (window.location.hash != '') ? '.' + window.location.hash.replace('#', '') : 'default'
```

This is an `if/then` statement that checks to see if the current hash is an empty string. If it is then `filter` will be set to `default` otherwise it will be set to the `window.location.hash` value (minus the `#`).

A URL like this, `index.html`, will result in `filter` being set to `default` and a URL like this, `index.html#my-selector`, will result in `filter` being set to `.my-selector`.

### Update

The reason your code isn't working doesn't actually have anything to do with my code, but here is an updated version of your code that I tested on your site:

```
$filterLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $filterLinks.filter('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');
    
    // get selector from data-filter attribute
    var selector = $this.data('option-value');
    
    $container'.isotope({
        filter: selector
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten the link to the jsFiddle, here it is http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/DA3wF/ going to try your answer now.

Comment: @elzi It works just fine, I pasted my code into your jsfiddle and walaa: http://jsfiddle.net/DA3wF/20/. I added `window.location.hash = 'blue';` to the top of your code to simulate a URL like this: `index.html#blue`.

Comment: I apologize, I was implementing it wrong... though now I have the same problem as I did with @Sindre Sorhus' answer - it won't sort after now. See here: http://nerdi.net/isotope-test2.html

Comment: @elzi The sort functionality seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/DA3wF/20/. That's a good place to start, what's different about that jsfiddle and your page on nerdi.net?

Comment: @elzi In the nerdi.net/isotope-test2.html page you use this line: `selector = $this.data('filter');`. A couple things, **1)** use `var selector = ...` so you don't create a global variable. **2)** There doesn't appear to be a `data-filter` attribute on the filter links but there is a `data-option-value` attribute. So the code inside your `click` event handler should look like this: `var selector = $this.data('option-value');`.

Comment: @elzi See the update to my answer for why your code isn't currently working.

Comment: Ah - sorry, playing with too many versions. Also - it looks like it IS indeed working by changing the hash - it just only showed after a refresh. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
filter: window.location.hash.replace('#', '.')
```

The location.hash will return "#green", we just replace it with a dot to get ".green".

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mofle/6AHAz/) with example of how to also change the selected link based on the hash.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. That works - but the problem now is that I can't sort afterwards... see here: http://nerdi.net/isotope-test.html#filter2 

Also - trying to change the # in the URL to filter doesn't work.

Comment: Sorting afterwards works in the jsfiddle, so the problem is probably something you did different on your site. Your question was how you could sort on page load using an hash. If you need to sort after pageload by changing the hash, you'll need to bind an event listener to the hashchange event, and update the filter, though this is out of the scope of this question.